# android accessing existing sqlite database on the device

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am programming an application for the iconia tab (android 3.0). In this application I want to access a sqlite database that is already existing. In the emulator it worked well, but on the device it seems i can't find the right folder where I should place the database. I rooted the device. I thought maybe if i create a database in the program I might see where it is positioned but when I am searching for it, the result is that it's nowhere.

Constructor of the database:

```
        public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, "blub.db", null, 1);
        }
```

accessing the database:

```
public void showTestValues(){
            ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
            Cursor cursor;
            Log.d("myLog", "showTestValues");
            try
            {
                // this is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
                // the cursor object store the information collected from the
                // database and is used to iterate through the data.
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM artikel ", null);

                // move the pointer to position zero in the cursor.
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                // if there is data available after the cursor's pointer, add
                // it to the ArrayList that will be returned by the method.
                if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        rowArray.add(cursor.getString(0));
                        Log.d("myLog", cursor.getString(0));
                    }
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

                // let java know that you are through with the cursor.
                cursor.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Error code:

```
 05-23 15:05:59.220: INFO/SqliteDatabaseCpp(7217): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: artikel, db=/data/data/com.example.inspiratedshopping/databases/blub.db
```

I tried to push the database on the direction data/data/com.example.inspiratedshopping/databases with the adb file explorer in eclipse - i get the error:

"Failed to push selection: No such file or directory"

so i used the file expert explorer on the device and it was possible to place the database. But you see the error up there.

Anyone has experience with that? 
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You probably do not have code to create the database, and you should create the path if does not exists. Anyway having two times /data/data looks unfamiliar. Please look into.

Comment: thanks for your answer. no, i don't have code to create the database because it is already existing and I just want to read it. What looks unfamilar to you? I found in all tutorials that databases are stored in /data/data/your.applications.package/databases.

Comment: You are going to find it quite challenging even on a rooted device to access a database created by another application, unless it's an application of your own which shares a userid with the application trying to access it or has made the database file world accessable and put it in a known place.  It is possible if rooted, but difficult as you have to do the tricky parts from stand alone executables, not java or jni code.

Comment: I created the database on my own on a desktop system because it needed some calculation time. Do you think I should place the database on a remote system and get the data with something like RMI? Isn't there a smarter solution?

Comment: and why is it working on the emulator but not the device??

Answer (score 0):

Have a gander at this blog post. If you have a database that is already existing, it would need to be included, as far as I know, in the Assets folder.

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: As I'm reading over that post and others related to this on StackOverflow, take special note that it appears that you have to follow the steps in copying the database from assets to another location first.

Comment: right I see and that might not be possible for databases larger than 1 mb ... mine has about 20 mb

Comment: Why is it necessary to copy the database from the /assets/ folder to another location? Why can't I just read directly from the database in /assets/ ?